# nginx reverse proxy returns encoded javascript and css

Tags: http, nginx

When accessing the site via my nginx proxy only the `html` loads in correctly. The `css` and `javascripts` that are returned are gibberish. But when I directly access the site the javascript is loaded correctly. I don't Know why I get this weird response.

[image: chrome dev tools - network response]

All the requests are `GET-requests` and their responses are always `200`. Weird thing is I don't see anything strange in the logs. I also tried turning of `GZIP` but that did not solve it

This is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name wut.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.1.60/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had gzip turned on and still it did not work. turns out that you need to upgrade the http version from 1.0 --> 1.1

by adding this line in the `location` block the problem dissapears: `proxy_http_version 1.1;`